# Prove that the equivalent number of bits per pixel for the YUV 4:2:0 scheme is 12

Tags: colors, yuv, subsampling

Prove that the equivalent number of bits per pixel for the YUV 4:2:0 scheme is 12

Comment: the question is
Suppose a camera has 576 lines per frame, 720 pixels per line, and a 25 Hz frame rate. The color subsampling scheme is 4:2:0. This camera applying DV compression at a constant data rate of 25 Mbits/s. Calculate the compression ratio applied to each video frame.

Comment: Did someone downvote because the query is in the form of a command? Please just convert in your head. This question is very relevant to stacks and overflows when developing pixel format related code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The number of bits to store 4 pixels in YUV 4:2:0 is:

```
4*8+8+8=48 bits
```

i.e. 4 bytes for luma and one byte for each color plane

which gives an average of

```
48/4=12bpp
```